# Measuring similarity between binary lists

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, similarity

I've two binary lists that I'm attempting to compare. To compare I sum where each corresponding value is equal and transform this to a percentage :

```
import numpy as np

l1 = [1,0,1]
l2 = [1,1,1]

print(np.dot(l1 , l2) / len(l1) * 100)
```

prints 66.666

So in this case l1 and l2 are 61.666 in terms of closeness. As each list is less similar the closeness value decreases.

For example using values :

```
l1 = [1,0,1]
l2 = [0,1,0]
```

returns 0.0

How to plot `l1` and `l2` that describe the relationship between `l1` and `l2` ? Is there a name for using this method to measure similarity between binary values ?

Using a scatter :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter( 'x', 'y', data=pd.DataFrame({'x': l1, 'y': l2 }))
```

produces :

[image]

But this does not make sense ?

Update :

"if both entries are 0, this will not contribute to your "similarity"

Using updated code below in order to compute similarity, this updated similarity measure includes corresponding 0 values in computing final score.

```
import numpy as np

l1 = [0,0,0]
l2 = [0,1,0]

print(len([a for a in np.isclose(l1 , l2) if(a)]) / len(l1) * 100)
```

which returns :

```
66.66666666666666
```

Alternatively, using below code with measure `normalized_mutual_info_score` returns 1.0 for lists that are the same or different, therefore `normalized_mutual_info_score` is not a suitable similarity measure ?

```
from sklearn.metrics.cluster import normalized_mutual_info_score

l1 = [1,0,1]
l2 = [0,1,0]

print(normalized_mutual_info_score(l1 , l2))

l1 = [0,0,0]
l2 = [0,0,0]

print(normalized_mutual_info_score(l1 , l2))
```

prints :

```
1.0
1.0
```

Comment: why not simply take the union of the two sets, and compare that to the length of the sets. seems easier

Comment: You are computing the cross-correlation (expressed as a percentage). You do realize, that this is an imperfect similarity measure? Specifically, if both entries are `0`, this will not contribute to your "similarity". For a true similarity measure (in this case, anyway), I would compute the normalized mutual information (there is an implementation in `scikit-learn`, for example).

Comment: @PaulBrodersen please see question update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the plot does not make sense. What you are doing is essentially an *inner product* between vectors. According to this metric `l1` and `l2` are supposed to be vectors in a 3D (in this case) space, and this measures whether they face the same a similar direction and have similar length. The output is a *scalar value* so there's nothing to plot.

If you want to show the individual contribution of each component, you *could* do something like

```
contributions = [a==b for a, b in zip(l1, l2)]
plt.plot(list(range(len(contributions)), contributions)
```

but i'm still not sure that this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def unpackbits(a, n):
    ''' Unpacks an integer `a` to n-length binary list. ''' 
    return [a >> i & 1 for i in range(n-1,-1,-1)]


def similarity(a, b, n):
    ''' Similarity between n-length binary lists obtained from unpacking
    the integers a and b. '''
    a_unpacked = unpackbits(a, n)
    b_unpacked = unpackbits(b, n)
    return np.sum(np.isclose(a_unpacked, b_unpacked))/n


# Plot
n = 3
x = np.arange(2**n+1)
y = np.arange(2**n+1)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, x)
z = np.vectorize(similarity)(yy[:-1,:-1], xx[:-1,:-1], n)

labels = [unpackbits(i, n) for i in x]
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('binary', n+1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pc = ax.pcolor(x, y, z, cmap=cmap, edgecolor='k', vmin = 0, vmax=1)
ax.set_xticks(x + 0.5)
ax.set_yticks(y + 0.5)
ax.set_xlim(0, 2**n)
ax.set_ylim(0, 2**n)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=45)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
cbar = fig.colorbar(pc, ax=ax, ticks=[i/n for i in range(n+1)])
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('similarity', fontsize=14)
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]